# Duda contar cuantas veces se repite un arrelo en swift

Tags: swift4

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

buenas noches estoy recién en swift estudiando y trato de contar por ejemplo la palabra Beach con un for in pero no me da resultado.. Gracias

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Contar todas las true y todas las false que están dentro de un array en swift](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/199508/contar-todas-las-true-y-todas-las-false-que-est%c3%a1n-dentro-de-un-array-en-swift)

Comment: @RuslanLópez el duplicado sería al revés, aunque las preguntas son del mismo usuario, ésta se publicó primero que la que tu mencionas en tu comentario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No lo cuentes con el for. Swift tiene cosas mejores. Buscas la palabra y luego la cuentas

```
let hay = tripDestinationVotes.filter({$0 == .beach}).count
```

Comment: muchas gracias lo logre con tu ayuda llevaba horas sin resolverlo con arto código y tu con una sola linea los solucionaste me salió con un print el resultado.