# Contar todas las true y todas las false que están dentro de un array en swift

Tags: array, swift4

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buenas noches estoy aprendiendo swift 4 y me pille con este ejercicio que no logro resolver y eh intentado intensamente resolverlo y no le encuentro la solución. ayuda por favor

Comment: Cuál es el problema? Que quieres lograr y cuál es tu resultado actual?

Comment: Hola buenas noches , lo que quiero lograr es contar todas las true y todas las false que están dentro de un array y mi resultado que me da con el código de arriba es que me cuenta todas en general sin poder contar los true y false por separado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No veo nada malo en tu código.

```
import Foundation

let ChangeVotes: [Bool] = [true,true,true,false,false,true]
let numTrue = ChangeVotes.filter({$0 == true}).count
let numFalse = ChangeVotes.filter({$0 == false}).count

print("Cantidad true: \(numTrue)")
print("Cantidad false: \(numFalse)")
```

Imprime:

```
Cantidad true: 4
Cantidad false: 2
```

Puedes comprobarlo guardando este código en un archivo "archivo.swift" y ejecutandolo en tu terminal con **`swift archivo.swift`** o en [swift playground](http://online.swiftplayground.run/)

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo lo voy a probar cuando llegue del trabajo muchas gracias

Comment: Muchas gracias lo hice y me resultó me falto imprimir no mas cosas simple se olvidas o te dan dolores de cabeza jajaja gracias por tu tiempo.